# Lightweight way to handle concurrency for a lot of instances

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have a class `HostServer` which contains my instances of an other kind of servers (actually Minecraft servers) and this host class may be created more than a 100 times (depending on the user). So I wanted to know, what would be a good way to handle concurrency for a considerable amount of instances (for the host class)? I have thought that I could use locks (`ReentrantReadWriteLock`), but it may be quite heavy if there is a lot of instances.

Thank you for your answers

EDIT (answers to the comments):

I actually need to share the resources because there is an updater thread and the others just read the data.

My needs are to have most recent data, so I need to handle the fact that if a thread reads and an other ones writes, the write has to come first. Although, I don't want the code to be too heavy because I may have a lot of instances (for the host class, from 10 to a 1000 and for the Minecraft server class, from 20 to 10000).

The actual code: https://github.com/devcreart/GameStack/blob/develop/server/src/main/java/fr/creart/gamestack/server/server/HostServer.java

Thanks again

Comment: The best way to handle concurrency is to not. If you can avoid shared resources, then do.

Comment: It totally depends on what you need / want to do exactly. Without more information, it's impossible to say if a lock such as `ReentrantReadWriteLock` is appropriate for what you want to do, or some other solution.

Comment: show your code so far

Comment: I've updated the post

Comment: "concurrency" and "instances" are words that don't belong together.  When we talk about "concurrency" we usually are talking about concurrent _computations_, concurrent _method calls_, etc.  Instances only enter in to the picture when we have to worry about shared access to them from two or more threads.

Comment: Re, "if a thread reads and an other ones writes, the write has to come first."  There is no _general_ solution to that problem.  If your threads need to do certain operations in a certain order, then it's up to you to write code that makes it happen that way.  But!...  Usually, the _best_ way to perform a sequence of operations in a specific order is to do those operations from within a single thread.

Comment: So what should I do? Create a thread which performs actions and calls futures/callables when read is needed?

Answer (score 0):

Premature optimization is a root of evil.

If you don't know exactly that you have a performance problem just do the simple solution.

If you have some requirements or some assumptions then try to create load test and do a conclusion after it.

But if you have a performance problem right now try to move out a shared state to some non-blocking data structure.

Comment: Sure, I just wanted to prevent future problems but you're right! What is a non-blocking data structure, though?

Comment: Data structure which isn't whole blocked when you work with it. Simplest example - ConcurrentHashMap.